# Whys are Assemby Attributes like AssemblyVersion missing in xproj?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-assembly, .net-core, assemblyinfo

Looking at the latest RC2 xproj projects, the AssemblyInfo.cs file is often missing several assembly attributes such as:

- `AssemblyTitle`
- `AssemblyDescription`
- `AssemblyCopyright`
- `AssemblyCulture`
- `AssemblyVersion`
- `AssemblyFileVersion`

When creating a web project, the AssemblyInfo is missing altogether. What is the reason for this and can/should we add them back in?

Comment: Fortunately, xproj/json mess has been abandoned now. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/

Comment: The xproj features are being moved to csproj, so this question may still be useful for the new csproj. If csproj will compile to NuGet packages, then my answer below will still be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, I discovered a partial answer. `project.json` contains a version number which is used to add `AssemblyFileVersion` and `AssemblyInformationalVersion` attributes at build time. The `AssemblyInformationalVersion` looks like it was added to handle version numbers with alpha characters which are used for pre-release semantic versioning.

Comment: Actually it even supports some more attributes for the various other versions and attributes. But let us not focus on that. Create a .cs file with all the attributes in it. Like good old times.